# complex integral over a line

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

The value of line integral over C of dz/(z^2+4) along the line x+y=1 in the direction of increasing x is ___ 
The answer is pi/2
I am not sure how to arrive at this answer .i had a guess that maybe i should apply residue theorem but not sure how to .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrate over a part of the line, add a large semi-circle (preferably the one that makes the closed curve positively oriented) and take the limit as the part of the line gets bigger and bigger.

Comment: thanks or your quick answer , is it possible to work it out so i can see how to proceed .
 i have lost touch with complex analysis ,since the last time i read anything similar was 6 years ago...it would be extremely helpful for my preparation for an exam.
Thanks !!